# Kivy ui is very slow on a RPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I use a Pi 3 Model B+ with Raspbian Stretch Desktop. I have written an app in python3 with a kivy ui. Later, the app is going to run on the rpi touchscreen. However, kivy is extremely slow. When i press a spinner it takes 3 second until it reacts.

As suggested here [Raspberry Pi Python (Kivy) extremely slow with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786122/raspberry-pi-python-kivy-extremely-slow-with-sudo) I added

```
  import os
  os.environ['KIVY_WINDOW'] = 'egl_rpi'
```

but it didn't help.

how to speed up kivy? or is the rpi just unable to render kivy faster?

This is my config.ini

```
[kivy]
keyboard_repeat_delay = 300
keyboard_repeat_rate = 30
log_dir = logs
log_enable = 1
log_level = info
log_name = kivy_%y-%m-%d_%_.txt
window_icon = 
keyboard_mode = 
keyboard_layout = qwerty
desktop = 1
exit_on_escape = 1
pause_on_minimize = 0
kivy_clock = default
default_font = ['Roboto', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf', 'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf']
log_maxfiles = 100
window_shape = data/images/defaultshape.png
config_version = 20

[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0

[input]
mouse = mouse
%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput

[postproc]
double_tap_distance = 20
double_tap_time = 250
ignore = []
jitter_distance = 0
jitter_ignore_devices = mouse,mactouch,
retain_distance = 50
retain_time = 0
triple_tap_distance = 20
triple_tap_time = 375

[widgets]
scroll_timeout = 250
scroll_distance = 20
scroll_friction = 1.
scroll_stoptime = 300
scroll_moves = 5

[modules]
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of reasons that makes your app slow, but first, check if it's common to all apps, or if it's something specific in yours. To do that, i'd encourage you to try with a simple app.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='test')

TestApp().run()
```

is pressing this button slow? If it is, i'd encourage looking at kivy configuration in general, maybe try putting multisampling to 0 or 1 in the config, check the logs for use of the right window provider, etc.

If it's decently performant, then try simplifying your app until the performances are decent again, you can enable the monitor module to check framerate easily, and the debugger module (flask required) to monitor memory usage. It's near impossible to give a general answer to this question, so a lot more specifics would be required, presumably after you narrowed the problem down a lot more.

Comment: I am new to kivi and the pi, and this test app I can see the button drawing. To me that seems really slow, some times with a screen tearing effect as half the button is drawn on one screen refresh adn the other half a split second later,  but is it slow or is it the best the pi can do?   it is a pi 3b+ with a 7 inch touch screen 1024x600 resolution

Comment: That seems like a driver issue there, or using an innefficient window provider in this situation, try with the egl_rpi one, and with the X11 one, as well as the SDL2 one, and compare.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't enabled OpenGL in raspi-config, after doing that it is much faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the gpu memory (via raspi-config). For me this helped in making the kivy app run smoothly.